# I have used Mr Clean Magic Eraser to clean my porcelain bowl, what to do next?

Tags: cleaning, kitchen-safety

According to https://gimmethegoodstuff.org/mr-clean-magic-eraser-is-it-toxic/

> You shouldn’t use it on dishes or something you eat off of as bits of the polymer are left behind. You should avoid formulas with added fragrance or bleach. All that said, as far as cleaning products go, Magic Eraser is actually one is among the safer options, especially considering how well it works.

I have used Mr. Clean Magic Eraser to cleaned a porcelain bowl. Should I throw my bowl away? Is there any protocol to clean my bowl afterward to remove any possible polymer on it?

I aware that [Mr. Clean Magic Eraser is made from formaldehyde-melamine-sodium bisulfite copolymer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melamine_foam) . My concern is if any trace amount of formaldehyde will enter food ware.

Comment: Perhaps you should supply more context. The blog you are quoting is in the context of getting rid of *absolutely anything* which isn't organic from a home. If that's your level of expectation, you should spell it out. If you are just a regular sane person, note that in the end the blogger too continues to use this product, and considers it safe.

Answer (score 8):

Just rinse it off. It sounds simple, but unless it's a very porous surface, a quick rinse should work fine. I would say you're even fine to continue washing your things with a Mr. Clean. I'm sure it's toxic to take a bite out of the "eraser" but I doubt very little (if any) should be left over on hard surfaces like porcelain, and would not likely hurt you in such small amounts.  I believe they even make one for washing dishes that is infused with Dawn soap (just don't use it on nonstick surfaces, which will be toxic and also ruin your pan).